# blank page when using php readfile() in wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form which the user fills out with their details & serial number, the software installer is then downloaded, named as their input. e.g. serial.exe

Once the form is submitted I check the file exists and then attempt the file download:

```
    $directory = get_template_directory();
    $file = $directory . '/filename.exe';

    if (file_exists($file)) {

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$Serial.'.exe"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        readfile($file);
        exit;
}
```

This causes the loading to freeze, nothing below this code is loaded but i can't see any errors & no file is generated.

If i change the file to a .png the code works.

I've also copied the same code to a php page outside of wordpress, the same code runs & downloads the file as desired.

Is it possible that Wordpress is somehow blocking the readfile() request because its an .exe?

**EDIT:**

It appears to be a problem with the size of the file, rather than the type of file.

A small .exe file has worked & is downloaded correctly.

Comment: Does the request "freeze" or does it finish with another response code? Is there anything written to the server's error log?

Comment: I can't see any errors, there are the IIS access requests but thats all, ive asked the hosting company if they have any errors i can't see

Comment: Then do all you can do: add dumps to the relevant code parts, check for the return code of your request

Comment: You shouldn't echo that "FILE EXISTS" at start. How it behaves when you remove that line?

Comment: Thanks MilanG, it behaved exactly the same, but i have removed to prevent any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that you have open output buffering. After the headers, use:

```
ob_clean(); /*not sure if this line is necessary*/
ob_end_flush();
readfile($file);
```

Found here: [blank page when using php readfile() in wordpress template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826755/blank-page-when-using-php-readfile-in-wordpress-template)